# Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException)

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an application that continually crashes with at Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException).  The full response to the crash when I run the debugger is:

```
Fan Laws [Android Application]  
    DalvikVM[localhost:8683]    
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException)) 
            Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(int, Object) line: 1404    
            Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Context, IBinder, IBinder, Activity, Intent, int) line: 1378  
            BrakeHP(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 2817    
            BrakeHP(Activity).startActivity(Intent) line: 2923  
            BrakeHP$1.onClick(View) line: 75    
            Button(View).performClick() line: 2408  
            View$PerformClick.run() line: 8816  
            ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
            ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
            Looper.loop() line: 123 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
        Thread [<6> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
        Thread [<5> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
        Thread [<7> Binder Thread #3] (Running)
```

It seems that it cannot find the Activity when I call it onClick.  I actually have an app in which the first screen asks you to choose one of four calculators in the app.  Click on a button and it gives you this one of four calculators.  They all come up fine.  You enter data and click the button on the calculator and it gives you an answer.  Only one of the calculators works, the other three crash with the above error.  The calculators are very similar as to their java files and how they are called in the manifest file.   But again only one works.  I have gone through all the similar posts on this topic with no success.  Any suggestions.

Comment: Can you also post the LogCat that occurs after your app dies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the activity to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: That was the problem, I had a few unrelated errors in my calls in the manifest file in three of the activities